# Having a SQL statement as WHERE clause in another SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is it possible to have another SQL query as the where statement as I tried below? The following query did not work for me. My goal is to select only the records from `NOR_LABOR` table which are the ID is greater than the current maximum ID in `ALL_LABOR_DETAILS` table where `work_center` column like %NOR%,

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(department), 
    RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator), 
    RTRIM(total_labor_hours), RTRIM(feet_produced),
    RTRIM(item_no), RTRIM(lot_no), RTRIM(default_bin), RTRIM(posted) 
FROM 
    NOR_LABOR
WHERE 
    ID IN (SELECT MAX(SOURCE_ID)
           FROM [STLEDGSQL01].[MES_DEV].[dbo].[ALL_LABOR_DETAILS] 
           WHERE work_center LIKE ('%NOR%') AND ID > MAX(SOURCE_ID))
ORDER BY 
    ID
```

Comment: Yes, but no. You can have a subquery, but this one wont work.

Comment: i don't see a group by in your inner query you are using aggregation function MAX

Comment: @trillion please advise how to edit this to work. I got stuck here and no clue how to make this query work. Thanks!

Comment: MAX() is an aggregation function GROUP BY is needed please search this online https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-group-by/

Comment: If you want IDs only that are greater than the current max source_Id, just change your `in` to `>` and drop the last `and` clause

Comment: You don't need a GROUP BY when using MAX() see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp

Comment: @SteveFord True but you can't use it in `WHERE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your description you are almost there, you just need a minor tweak:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(department), 
    RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator), 
    RTRIM(total_labor_hours), RTRIM(feet_produced),
    RTRIM(item_no), RTRIM(lot_no), RTRIM(default_bin), RTRIM(posted) 
FROM 
    NOR_LABOR
WHERE 
    ID > (SELECT MAX(SOURCE_ID)
           FROM [STLEDGSQL01].[MES_DEV].[dbo].[ALL_LABOR_DETAILS] 
           WHERE work_center LIKE ('%NOR%'))
ORDER BY 
    ID
```

Comment: Thank you, quick question. Is it possible to have 2 tables in 2 different servers? Because when I run this query it gives me this error "Could not find server 'STLEDGSQL01' in sysservers. Execute sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers." But I know there's no any typo or anything and the 'NOR_LABOR' table is in 'NORMAC' server but 'ALL_LABOR_DETAILS' is in the 'STLEDGSQL01' server.

Comment: Well yes - however your sample query as you presented it uses `[STLEDGSQL01]` as if it was a working linked server; if you are having trouble with linked servers then that's a different question and a different answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try some workarounds and if no luck I'll open a new question. Thank you again, really appreciate. I think your answer is right it's just my servers probably I will have to figure out :)